# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly' in Django

Tags: python, django, pip, plotly, conda

As you can see, I have successfully installed plotly in my Django project.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\user\source\VVV\V_Project> pip list
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- -------------------
plotly                             5.13.1
```

However, it keeps showing the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\source\VVV\V_Project\mysite\Plotly.py", line 3, in <module>
    from plotly.offline import plot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'
```

My code is as follow.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go

def index(request):
    x_data = [0,1,2,3]
    y_data = [x**2 for x in x_data]
    plot_div = plot([Scatter(x=x_data, y=y_data,
                        mode='lines', name='test',
                        opacity=0.8, marker_color='green')],
               output_type='div')
    return render(request, "plotly.html", context={'plot_div': plot_div})
```

I don't know why it cannot find the module `plotly`. Please help me.

Comment: Try renaming file Plotly.py to something else.

Comment: I tried but it still does not work.

Comment: Are you using virtual env? Are you using conda?

Comment: I use conda. It works normally in Jupyter but does not work in visual studio.

Comment: Then make sure that you have activated the correct conda environment in Visual Studio. You can check this by going to the terminal window in Visual Studio and typing `conda info --envs`. This will show you a list of all the available conda environments on your system. Make sure that the environment you want to use is listed and has a `*` next to it, indicating that it is currently active.

Comment: @CanaryTheBird. You speak about `conda` but I see `pip` in your question. Maybe you have used `pip` from other global python installation, or an other conda  environment. To be sure that pip install in the good conda environment, you have to type  the complete path  like `anaconda3/envs/bin/pip` or to determine the location of current `python`. https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/

Comment: And `conda activate myenv` before execute `pip`.