# Pip list showing random packages when Changing python versions in conda env

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, miniconda

Below are the step/chronology:

1. I create a conda env using `conda create --name xkcd`    and activated it using `conda create xkcd`
2. I check my python version using `python --version` which comes out to be 3.11.5
3. Now I do `pip list` to see if any random packages are installed.. They aren't yet. I see only pip,openssl,setuptools,wheel.
4. I want python 3.10 for my project (mandatorily to match other devs), so I do `conda install python=3.10`
5. Now I again do `pip list` and see random packages from my other conda envs being listed , while `conda list` shows only the appropriate packages
6. Another mandate in my project is that I have to use a pypi repo (https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/azure-sdk/public/_packaging/azure-sdk-for-python/pypi/simple/) for installing some packages which are not available in conda (because conda points to an internal repo my firm has).
7. So when I use pip to install something, it looks at the random packages it found in point #5 , and it's messing up with my installations.

**Side Notes**

I am using miniconda

I am in windows and when I do where pip, I see 2 pips - one from my conda env (C:\UBS\Dev.conda\envs\devoai\Scripts\pip.exe) and the other from C:\Program Files\choco\miniconda . Is this weird ?

Also I suspect there is some caching issue as I am damn sure the random packages I see coming in are not any usual pip/python dependencies or default packages (for example- tiktoken package)

Comment: Maybe you have used pip from other global python installation, or an other conda environment. To be sure that pip install in the good conda environment, you have to type the complete path like anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/pip or to determine the location of current python.


And conda activate myenv before execute pip.

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75703695/10489562

Comment: @phili_b I have tried using the full path to to pip.exe, Still the same results.

Comment: "and the other from C:\Program Files\choco\miniconda" you have to type `conda activate devoai` before.

Comment: @phili_b I was already doing this man. It's an obvious step, but I will add it in the question's body. Still nothing works...

Comment: See duplicate. This is very likely due to user site packages. Since user site only loads matching Python versions (through minor, e.g., 3.10 or 3.11), then the reported behavior indicates that the user site has Python 3.10 packages, but not Python 3.11.